# Need help in creating grok pattern that works for both the following type of logs

Tags: elastic-stack, logstash-grok, grok

Create a new line in the log with a grok pattern. This is the current pattern

**%{DATE:date} %{TIME:time} %{LOGLEVEL:log_level} %{WORD:log_type} [%{DATA:kafka_msg}] - [%{DATA:file_line}.] %{WORD:module_name} %{GREEDYDATA:msg}**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2IGC.png)

We need to create a grok pattern for this log